# OpenAPI adding underscore to properties that have same names as access modifiers in Angular

Tags: angular, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

In my model definition I have a property called "public" as part of an object. When running the swagger code-gen, it generates the code for my object, but it adds an underscore to the "public" property. So my object looks as follows:

```
export interface ObjectInfo { 

    _public?: boolean;

}
```

I'd like the property to just be called "public", as follows:

```
export interface ObjectInfo { 
    
        public?: boolean;
    
}
```

Angular does not have an issue with you doing:

```
public public: boolean;
```

So not sure why OpenAPI feels the need to add the underscore. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but maybe this helps other people like myself:

You can define a mapping for reserved words when generating. Config is called `reservedWordsMappings`: [Official readme](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md)

Also from the official readme:

> specifies how a reserved name should be escaped to. Otherwise, the default `_<name>` is used. For example `id=identifier`. You can also have multiple occurrences of this option

In my case of using the maven plugin my config looks like this (had to map `in` to `in` since my backend doesnt know how to handle jpa criterias with `_in`):

```
.....
<configuration>
    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi/api-docs.yaml</inputSpec>
    <generatorName>typescript-axios</generatorName
    <reservedWordsMappings>in=in</reservedWordsMappings>
    ...
</configuration>
.....
```